# Managing primary keys between data lake and oracle db

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-data-lake, data-ingestion

I have setup an ingest pipeline for streaming json data which gets ingested into AWS S3 data lake through pyspark and also Oracle db.

In Oracle db, primary keys are created using sequences.
What is the most efficient way I can design the data lake ingestion to have the primary keys always in-sync with the oracle db?

Both the ingestions happen parallely.

Comment: Pass all of the data through Oracle to receive the primary key from the same source, before placing it in the data lake. If the data doesn't have a natural primary key, you won't be able to synchronize it later. The only alternative I see is not to use sequences at all, but rather to have the primary key generated by the ingest logic so that it can be applied to both streams as the data comes from the source.

Comment: What would be the best way to have both heterogenous systems use the same key generation logic?

Comment: You won't be able to synchronize heterogenous generation methods in parallel: there really isn't a way to guarantee the same result in each. You either need to serialize your stream and use *one* database to create the primary key before copying again to the second database, or create the key *in* the stream *before* you split it to two parallel destinations (i.e. create the key at the source). Either way, create the key in *one* place and then make copies of the data to additional destinations.